# Change format of date column to be month and day only in r

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a dataframe that consists of a date column which I have converted from a char to a POSIXlt class.

I then successfully split this into two new columns; 1 for date as yyyy-mm-dd and one as time. However, I wish to drop the year in the new date column and I have tried using the format "%m/d%", and using lubridate again with the m/d format, as well as other things but the year still remains.

Can anyone help?

```
       SETTLEMENTDATE TOTALDEMAND   RRP       DATE     TIME
1 2010-01-01 00:30:00     7809.31 21.50 2010-01-01 00:30:00
2 2010-01-01 01:00:00     7483.69 20.98 2010-01-01 01:00:00
3 2010-01-01 01:30:00     7117.23 20.06 2010-01-01 01:30:00
4 2010-01-01 02:00:00     6812.03 17.93 2010-01-01 02:00:00
5 2010-01-01 02:30:00     6544.33 17.43 2010-01-01 02:30:00
6 2010-01-01 03:00:00     6377.32 16.85 2010-01-01 03:00:00
```

```
> class(NSW_2010)
[1] "data.frame"
```

```
> class(NSW_2010$DATE)
[1] "Date"
```

So to recap, I wish to change the DATE column to be month & day only so that use this column in two different data frames to plot a line graph and show the difference between the two columns across the two data sets.

Answer (score 0):

`format` should help -

```
NSW_2010$DATE_MONTH <- format(NSW_2010$DATE, "%m/%d")
```

For example, with `Sys.date()` -

```
format(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d")
#[1] "07/30"
```

Comment: Thank you. It creates the format I want (12/20) but it stores it as char and not date. I then have problems creating line graphs and I am not sure if that is because I am trying to do it on a char variable. Is there a way to make DATE_MONTH a date?

Comment: No, date has fixed format. (YYYY-MM-DD) everything else is just character. If you are using ggplot for plotting I would suggest to keep the dates as it is and use functions like `scale_x_date` or `scale_x_datetime` to format labels as per your choice.

Comment: The challenge was the two datasets were 10 years apart so when I plotted, because the x axis was using date which had the year in it, it was plotting what looked like a vertical line for 2010 to the far left and then a similar vertical line for 2020.. rather than a data point for each day in the month and ignoring the year.
It is helpful to know date has a fixed format of YYYY-MM-DD .. I will stop trying to figure out how to change it to just MM-DD but retain date format. Thank you.

Comment: Well, the issue is the questions asks to change date to month and day format which the answer does but it seems your original issue was something else as mentioned in above comment.  The question does not include information about that at the time of me posting the answer so it was difficult for me to answer.