# extract 'month-day' or 'day-month' from date-class and keep date-class

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

The example with some dates and transformation into date

```
library(lubridate)
date <- c('2018-01-09', '2018-01-10')
date = ymd(date)
```

I'm trying to extract month and day from the dates and keep them in one column of date-class:

```
date <- format(date, "%m-%d")
```

the class is changed from `date` to `chr`, but I want to keep the `date` class. What should I do?

Comment: Afaik you can't do that; date class has to have a year.

Comment: This is not possible. See here comment of @Ronak Shah <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172798/change-format-of-date-column-to-be-month-and-day-only-in-r>: "No, date has fixed format. (YYYY-MM-DD) everything else is just character. If you are using ggplot for plotting I would suggest to keep the dates as it is and use functions like scale_x_date or scale_x_datetime to format labels as per your choice."

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` class in R represents an object as the number of days since 1970/01/01. This cannot be done for a month and day with no year.

You might consider an alternative representation that captures both month and day in one vector: day of year `lubridate::yday(date)`